# AngularJS how to change jquery component when a service attribute value changes

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have an AngularJS 1.0.7 web app.

I´m using a JQuery-UI datepicker component integrated within a directive. In the other hand, my application is localized in english and spanish.

I have a service that holds the language locale. Whenever the locale changes, I would like to change the jquery datepicker component locale.

I have seen examples in JQuery here: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization . It´s easy. But the problem is that I need to access the jquery component from a service.

I guess this is not the Angular way. How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE**

Well, I have found this post, [DOM manipulation in AngularJS services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925547/dom-manipulation-in-angularjs-services).
So, my scenario could fit with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It´s working. If can update the DOM element from the service.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that comes to my mind is: you can hold your locale value (for example `en-US`) in a `service`,`factory`, or even `value` and then on your directive `$watch` on that particular value, when it changes, you can change/re-render your component with the prefered value. This I think is the Angular way of doing it ;)

Hope I could answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

If changing the `locale` is the only need of then no need to go for `service` just simply watch for the localization of the `datepicker` and in the watch handler call the option as follows.

```
 $scope.$watch("locale",function(newVal,oldVal){
  angular.element("#datepicker").datepicker( "option",$.datepicker.regional[newVal] )
  });
```