# Why DOM manipulation is not preferred in service in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive

I know it is bad practice to have the DOM manipulation in anywhere other than directive. but I do not understand why is it a bad practice to have the DOM manipulation in the service/factory as we can reuse them.

I have searched online and also found the same question on stackoverflow 
[stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925547/dom-manipulation-in-angularjs-services)

but still not clear with the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Angular follows [declarative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming) principle which means

> a style of building the structure and elements of computer
>   programs—that expresses the logic of a computation without describing
>   its control flow

At the same time `services` in angular were introduced to contain business logic. If business flow is complex - imperative approach suites better.

In such a way if you have DOM manipulation in the service you probably violate [separation of concerns principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), as you are coupling UI and business layers. And coupling itself eventually ends up in spagetti-code when this "reusable" components (according to new requirements) should look a bit different in the modules where they were integrated

Answer (score 0):

Directives, by definition, are always attached to a DOM node. So when we create a directive, it either expands or replaces the DOM node.
services are engaged with directives so we are able to manipulate view of an app through directives. however, there are cases where you might need to manipulate DOM element(s) via a service, like in a modal window. 
I have a rule of thumb for situations like this. can DOM manipulation be done directly with the attached node? and answer to this question tells me if I need to use a directive (yes) or a service (no) but overall it depends on complexity of your project as well.